# How to send an email to a list of email in a kind in Google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

HY!

I have a list in GAE, around 300 entries and I would like to send an email to everyone.
I've already prepared a script that get all enterprises and then makes a loop for each one and in each iteration it sends an email.
Now im concerned with timeout. If I do all the thing in one step, it might take too much time and then i dont know to who i sent or not.

My script is like this:

```
from models.Enterprise import Enterprise
from google.appengine.api import mail

esq = Enterprise.all()
es = esq.fetch(1000) # normally around 300

for e in es:
   mail.send_mail(sender="myemail", to=str(e.email), subject="...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to delegate this task to a [taskqueue](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) that provides a fairly high timeout set to 10 minutes.

Comment: thanks, I will check it out. I still don't know how to use it, but I will read some docs (: (maybe you can give me a quick tip?xD)